# Robots.txt disallow specific page doesn't work

Tags: magento, seo, robots.txt

I've a Magento installation and i want to exclude the privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode page from Google crawling.
In my robots.txt i've set the following code:

```
Disallow: /enable-cookies/
Disallow: /customer-service/
Disallow: /privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode/
```

When i analize my website with SemRush i get duplicated content with this page and the disallow istruction doesn't seem to work.

Any advise?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Google Help Page:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en

> Google does not recommend blocking crawler access to duplicate content
>   on your website, whether with a robots.txt file or other methods. If
>   search engines can't crawl pages with duplicate content, they can't
>   automatically detect that these URLs point to the same content and
>   will therefore effectively have to treat them as separate, unique
>   pages.